# How to call a post method from api in a loop Angular

Tags: api, angular, post, promise

I am trying to do a put request to an api from array that I have. The post wants an object, and I have an array of objects. What I do is a loop itereting the length of my array of objects calling the method into my service. The problem is that just works the first one and the rest are not working. Do I should something like return promise and then call it recursively?

Here I let my method to call the api:

```
onUpdate() {
for (var i = 0; i < this.conditionsToUpdate.length; i++) {
      this.ruleService.updateConditionsFromRule(this.rule.id, this.conditionsToUpdate[i])
    .then(_ => {
      this.notificationService.addToast('Condition Updated!', '', 2)
    })
    .catch(err => this.notificationService.handleError("Could not update the 
      condition!"))
 }
}
```

Finally, on my Service I have my request:

```
updateConditionsFromRule(idRule: number, condition: ConditionUpdate):Promise<any> {
 return this.http.post(`${this.organizationId}/rules/${idRule}/conditions`, condition)
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => {
    const response = <{ id: String, error: IError[] }>res.json();
    if (!!response && !!response.error) {
      return Promise.reject(response.error)
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    }
  }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
 }
```

And as I said, it just returns me the first post we do, the rest are not being created.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable` for this, promises will be too limited.

given your array `updateConditionsFromRule`, this is how to implement such a thing:

```
let requests:Observable<Response>[] = [];
updateConditionsFromRule.forEach( updateCondition => {
  requests.push(this.http.post(`${this.organizationId}/rules/${idRule}/conditions`, condition));
});

// After our loop, requests is an array of Observables, not triggered at the moment.

//Now we use combineLatest to convert our Observable<Response>[] to a Observable<Response[]>.
//This means that the promise will resolve once the last request of the array has finished.

Observable.combineLatest(requests).toPromise()
  .then(res => {
    const response = <{ id: String, error: IError[] }>res.json();
    if (!!response && !!response.error) {
      return Promise.reject(response.error)
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    }
  }).catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
 }
```